# SQL XML Query results in same data field?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am writing a simple SQL Query that drills into an XML and pulls out every value that has the same location I specify. This is the query:

```
> SELECT o.Created
>, o.PurchaseXML.query('/Basket/Skus/Sku/Code[1]')
>
>FROM [Order] o
>
>JOIN OrderStatus os
>ON os.OrderStatusID = o.[Status]
>
>WHERE os.IsSuccessful = 1 AND o.Created >= '12/24/12'
```

However when i am getting an output of results the data from the XML Query are being placed in the same data cell. As below:

[image]

Is there a way to code this so i get the values in in seperate columns that are picked up from each order?

Thankyou for your help

Greg

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly by "in separate columns" - maybe write down an example. Since there can be an arbitrary number of in each order, you'd get an arbitrary number of columns, which is not making much sense.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include details of the language/environment you are running this in. This is not a generic SQL/XML question.

Comment: I would like the column with the XML values to be seperated into seperate columns whenever a new result is found from the XML Query i perform. As when i use the /text() function after the address of the XML value i get one long string of results that is very hard to read.

Comment: I am running this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, from a Local Server of my company? Not sure if that helps :S sorry.

Comment: How many codes for each row do you expect to see? In this sample the max number is 3 codes. Dynamic number of columns is a bit complicated since you first have to figure out how many columns you actually need before building a dynamic SQL statement. It would be a lot easier to write a query for a known number of columns that you know for sure is enough.

Comment: Yes i totally agree. Ok no bother. If there isnt a simple answer it is fine. I will just export the results as .csv to excel and split the cell that way. Thankyou very much for your help anyway. The question was more to make the query more presentable. No bother though. Thankyou.

Comment: Would it be of any help to have each Code on a separate row (e.g. the Created column would then contain duplicates for the baskets with multiple SKUs)?